# Running Bill pay formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to create an Excel spreadsheet to keep track of a remaining total due for bills. My train of thought is to log the company of Bills due in `Column A`, `Column B` will have the Amounts due, `Column C` will have the dates due and in `Column D` I want to be able to enter "paid".

Basically what I'm wanting is to have Excel calculate the total of all the bills and if it is marked "paid" in `Column D`, then subtract that amount from the total of all bills and have the formula work independently if not paid in order.

I know it is some kind of IF STATEMENT, but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to put it, is that you want to sum all amounts in column `B` whose corresponding value in column `D` is *not* "paid". You can do this with a `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(D:D,"<>paid",B:B)
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused, in Column C I have the due dates. What would I change to use this formula?

Comment: Sorry confused columns `B` and `C`. See the edit of my answer

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed!